# React - Need help converting path to string so users get redirected to Stripe when clicking img

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-router, stripe-payments

So let me explain what's going on. I have this component called `PaymentAccountLandingPage` and in that component I import and render this component `ConnectedAccountsButton` which is a Stripe button that I created using a Stripe image and essentially making it just like button. So I want users to be redirected to the landing page for creating an account with Stripe when they click `img/button`. The problem is to do that I need to make an axios call with `createAcctLink` so that it returns a pathname that contains an `accountId` that I need to have in the path (I XXXXXX'd out the acctId below obviously). But I need that info in the path because someone else on my team parses at a later point when they get redirected back the problem is the response data that comes back from `response.item` is the following:

```
https://connect.stripe.com/express/onboarding/XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Note it is not a string and I even used the `toString` method to TRY and turn it into a string but no luck. Does anyone have any other solutions? I don't want to use `window.location.assign()` or `window.location.href` because I already know how to do it that way but the reason why I want to figure out another way is because that takes 10-15 seconds to redirect users to Stripe. The reason why I want to use `Link` `react-router-dom` is because it's fast and I know there's also `Redirect` but either way I need the path to be a string so that's my issue. If anyone has any solutions or workarounds that'd be awesome. Here's my `ConnectedAccountsButton`:

```
import React from "react";
import connectbutton from "@assets/images/stripe/ConnectedAccountsButton.png";
import { createAccountLink } from "../../services/connectedAccountsService";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class ConnectedAccountsButton extends React.Component {
  state = {
    path: "",
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    createAccountLink()
      .then(this.onAccountLinkSuccess)
      .catch(this.onAccountLinkError);
  }

  onAccountLinkSuccess = (response) => {
    let pathUrl = response.item.toString();
    console.log("Success Response:", pathUrl);
    this.setState(() => {
      return {
        path: pathUrl,
      };
    });
  };

  onAccountLinkError = (err) => {
    console.error("Error Response: ", err);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Link to={this.state.path}>
        <img
          src={connectbutton}
          style={{ width: "200px", cursor: "pointer" }}
          alt="Connected Accounts Link"
        />
      </Link>
    );
  }
}

export default ConnectedAccountsButton;
```

Comment: What data you receive on `response` in `onAccountLinkSuccess`?

Comment: I posted it above do you not see it? I said response.item: and then it returns a path the response is the path with the XXXXXX. I already check typeof and it says string. it doesn't make sense that it doesnt work. this is paradox. I even check react devtools and its the path as a string but for some reason when i click i get rerouted to one of my error routes which means the path isnt valid. Doesn't make sense because I can see the path in my dev tools and its a valid path as a string. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question because I figured out the solution with a friends help. The strange thing is we used `typeof` on `response.item` and it was already a string. There's no reason this shouldn't have worked but it didn't. We even checked the React Dev Tools and sure enough in state was the correct path but for some reason when I clicked the `img` it would send me to one of my error routes.

This is what ended up working:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import connectbutton from "@assets/images/stripe/ConnectedAccountsButton.png";
import { createAccountLink } from "../../services/connectedAccountsService";
import debug from "sabio-debug";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const _logger = debug.extend("ConnectedAccountsButton");

const ConnectedAccountsButton = () => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("");
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    createAccountLink().then(onAccountLinkSuccess).catch(onAccountLinkError);
  }, []);

  const redirectConnectedAccount = () => {
    history.push(url);
  };

  const onAccountLinkSuccess = (response) => {
    _logger("Success Response", response.item);
    setUrl(response.item);
  };

  const onAccountLinkError = (err) => {
    _logger("Error Response", err);
  };

  return (
    <img
      src={connectbutton}
      style={{ width: "200px", cursor: "pointer" }}
      alt="Connected Accounts Link"
      onClick={redirectConnectedAccount}
    />
  );
};

export default ConnectedAccountsButton;
```